# Custom Plugin throwing error "Key not present in dictionary" when OrganisationService Updates

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I have some code that updates an entity. Everything runs fine until it hits this line

```
AliasedValue orderproductAlias = (AliasedValue)product.Attributes["orderproduct.salesorderdetailid"];
Entity orderproduct = new Entity("salesorderdetail");
orderproduct.Id = (Guid)orderproductAlias.Value;
orderproduct.Attributes["salesorderdetailid"] = (Guid)orderproductAlias.Value;
orderproduct.Attributes["piv_myFeild"] = myFeildRef;
service.Update(orderproduct); //Code breaks on this line
```

The error I am getting is

```
Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.InvalidPluginExecutionException: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault]: The given key was not present in the dictionary. (Fault Detail is equal to Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault).
```

**UPDATE**

I do have a PreOrderProductUpdate method, but when putting a breakpoint in that code it does not stop so I can only assume the error is between these two points.

Comment: Are you sure `piv_myFeild` is correct ?

Comment: Yes I have checked the names everything is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
AliasedValue orderproductAlias = (AliasedValue)product.Attributes["orderproduct.salesorderdetailid"];

//-- Are you sure the above line is not throwing error ?


//-- Do you have the following check in your plugin code ?
if (context.Depth > 1)
  {
   return;
  }
```

**Change your code as below and try again:**

```
if(product.Attributes.Contains("orderproduct.salesorderdetailid"))
{
 AliasedValue orderproductAlias = (AliasedValue)product.Attributes["orderproduct.salesorderdetailid"];
 Entity orderproduct = new Entity("salesorderdetail");
 orderproduct.Id = ((EntityReference)orderproductAlias).Id; //It should be parsed as EntityReference not Guid
 orderproduct["piv_myFeild"] = myFeildRef;
 service.Update(orderproduct); //Code breaks on this line
}
```